# Is it possible to exact search Google photos by filename?

Tags: google-photos

I would like to search Google photos images by their filename but I have a problem when two photos were taken at the same time and therefore their filenames and pretty similar - e.g., ***20190430_092841.jpg*** and ***20190430_092841(0).jpg***. When searching the one with parenthesis, it works well but searching the other one displays both.

I have already tried both single and double quotation marks (both seems to do a different thing), plus and minus signs and many other symbols such as exclamation and quotation marks or backslashes with no luck.

Do you know if there is a way to force exact filename search which doesn't ignore (0) at the end of the filename? Or do you know about some online documentation about photos search?

In the end, I would like to search for multiple images at the same time with the use of ***OR*** keyword (which seems to work), but first I need to solve this.

Comment: try: `"20190430_092841"`

Comment: Sadly still doesn't work - no matter whether I add the **.jpg** extension or not...

Answer (score 2):

I spend one hour by chat with Google support today to finally have their answer: "the specialist said me that it's not possible for now; sorry"

*BUT* I **succeeded** to find an uploaded video by filename.

### Howto

1. goto **https://photos.google.com** url, and **NOT** https://photos.google.com/u/1/ as I did first (don't know why, searching for "Google Photos" on Google made me go there). Indeed, the Google Photos with the "/u/1" in the URL don't work. Don't ask me why
2. search for your file name, extension is not required (example: "my file")

nb: as detailed below, this can potentially gives you a LOT of files if your file includes a date in this name

### Details

- uploaded a little video file named `test upload.m4v`
- a few minutes later:

  - I can see the file in last uploaded files: [https://photos.google.com/search/\_tra\](https://photos.google.com/search/%5C_tra%5C)_
  - but searching for its name returns nothing:  https://photos.google.com/search/test%20upload
- **waiting** for a few hours (11 hours in my case), the file has been parsed and is now present in their database. I can find it searching for "test upload.m4v"

### This works **BUT** most of the time search results also includes other files

Typical use case for Google Photos is backup of Android phone's photos and videos. Those files typically have names like `IMG_20211012_183718.jpg`, and have datetime metadata that says "this photo was taken the 10 dec 2021".

Searching for this particular filename (searching for `IMG_20211012_183718.jpg` string) seems to be interpreted like this by Google Photo search:

- search for files that names matches "IMG", or "20211012", or "183718" (you can do the test yourself)
- **AND** that media content have been created on "20211012", ie 10 dec 2021

This search will actually match the searched file, as its name contains "IMG", "20211012" and "183718", but also potentially a bunch of other files:

- all photos and videos that have been taken on the same day (even if their names doesn't include "20211012", or "183718")

### Conclusion

- it's easy to find/isolate files that have filenames that doesn't date or datetime stamps on their names, as the search won't include all media items taken on this particular day
- it's difficult to identify/isolate files that contains dates in their names. And this is not a good new, as the typical usecase is to backup Android medias that basically always contains date or datetime information on filenames

Comment: "/u/1" was because you have loged in multiple google accounts.  The account that you want to search happend to be the second one.

Answer (score 2):

## Sum

- To search for file where filename includes date and time, **skip the date part and search by time part**.
- Include file extension to narrow the search result.
- Google Photos could return false positives if digit pattern [ aa-bb-cc ] appears in any order irrespective of [ - ] symbol in filename or visually in image, such as

  - *bb-aa-cc*,
  - *cc-bb-aa*,
  - *cc-aa-bb*,
  - *bb aa cc*,
  - *bbXccYYaa*.
  - However, Google Photos UI also has arrow indicator to day and date (e.g. *Wed, Jan 12*). This makes target file easy to browse/skip to.

    - Mind the timezone. In my case, in UTC +3, the date listed by Google Photos is behind by 3 hours (i.e. file modified at 2:55 AM on 1st of April is listed/shown as 31st of March).

## Details

### Target: [ 22-01-12-17-23-54.mp4 ]

- Context:

  - target video file uploaded 72+ hours ago
  - originally recorder/modified on 2022-01-12 at 17-23-54

    - = 12th of January 2022 at 17:23:54
  - 100k+ files/uploads in Google Photos

## Test

- Goal

  - minimize false positives
  - get to intended file in under 10 s

| Search | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 22-01-12-17-23-54.mp4 | #fails |
| "22-01-12-17-23-54.mp4" | #fails |
| '22-01-12-17-23-54.mp4' | #fails |
| 2022 01 12 17 23 54 .mp4 | #fails |
| 2022 january 12 17-23-54 .mp4 | #fails |
| 2022 january 12 "17-23-54" .mp4 | #fails |
| **17-23-54.mp4** | **#works** |
| **17-23-54 .mp4** | **#works** |
| 172354 .mp4 | #fails |
| 172354.mp4 | #fails |
| "172354" .mp4 | #fails |